# cclive: what kind of regexes are allowed?

Tags: regular-expression, download

Is there a place where I can look, what kind of regexes I can use with the `--tr` option from `cclive`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: this answer is based on Internet research without hands-on experience with the program.)*

CCLive supports the `--tr` option [since version 0.7.6](http://repo.or.cz/w/cclive.git/blob/HEAD:/NEWS). Until then the `--regexp` option could be used:

```
0.7.6  Mon Sep 12 2011  Toni Gundogdu
Changes:
    - Add --tr (depr. --regexp, --subst)
    - Add --prefer-format
    - Revise manual
```

Looking at the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/cclive.1.html), the `--tr` option states:

> Default is `"/(\w|\s)/g"`.

Since the regexp matching code is [based on libpcre](http://repo.or.cz/w/cclive.git/blob/HEAD:/INSTALL), I think the [standard Perl Regular Expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) are allowed.

The [source code](http://repo.or.cz/w/cclive.git/blob/HEAD:/src/cc/re.cpp) that performs regular expression matching is also available to browse. I cannot really put all things together, but that might be the place for any special options used for pcre.